# Extract video from sony handycame with perfect quality

Tags: opencv, video, camera, usb, resolution

I've got an old sony handycame that record into tapes.
When i try to display the videos in my samsung tv using RCA cables, the video is full screen and with a really good quality.

I wanted to transfer the videos into my computer using usb communication.
I've got the handycam's driver, installed, the handycam is recognized as well.

Using OpenCV library, have been able to collect the pictures but in a resolution of 320*240.

When i try to resize the pictures, the quality get really bad.
I would like to have videos of more than default resolution, with a good quality.

So, how come that the videos are displayed so well into the tv, but not in my computer ? and is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: This question might be better answered on another Stack Exchange site, such as [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: I suggest you ask at : **https://video.stackexchange.com/** mentioning all relevant details like model etc ... Also what happens when you try [**some researched solutions**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=handycam+%22tape%22+usb)? Have you considered an RCA to USB / HDMI converter cable? Do you think the 320x240 is an OpenCV (software) limit or it's because your camera (hardware) is before the "HD" and gigabytes era when a 320x240 digital video was good enough? So record from tape to DVD or via firewire transfer to get TV resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the RCA to USB / HDMI converter idea, i will try that.

And converning the 320*240, it's not OpenCV limit since i've already worked with this library and treated videos that have more than such resolution. I think it is so because of the screen of my handycam which has this resolution

And concerning firewire transfer , how come it would get TV resolution ? what difference between it and the usb method ?

Comment: Your taped video resolution is either in NTSC (720 x 486) or PAL (720 x 576). Firewire is like (a digital) SCART cable when you tape from TV to VHS but with it you transfer into file via a capture tool (eg: OpenCV?). USB method means camera chip must encode from analog (tape) to digital (bytes) then it gives you those bytes via USB cable. But you don't control the camera chip so you get whatever it's programmed to encode (eg small 320x240 video). Since Firewire expects you to do the encode part, it just gives raw original video, just play tape as you record/capture.

Comment: I got you ! , and the 320x240 must be so because of the small screen of the handycame ! , thanks for the informations it's so helpfull
Just another question: i still didn't buy a iLink (sony name of the firewire) cable, i googled it , but my computer doesn't have a iLink port, what suggestion can you give me ? a usb-to-ilink adapter for example ?
sorry for late answer